# Are there Java interpreters that bypass compilation?

Tags: java, groovy

Compiling and running a simple `HelloWorld` takes about 1 second in Java.

```
$ time javac HelloWorld.java 

real    0m0.659s
user    0m1.203s   <-- 1.2s
sys     0m0.113s
```

For comparison, Lua can do the same in about 0.002 seconds.

In some (admittedly unusual) applications, thousands of short-running Java applications are dynamically generated, so that 1 second can translate into **hours of compiling**.

I wonder if there are Java interpreters that bypass compilation to `*.class` files altogether?

(I know that there is Groovy, but it's not a strict superset of Java)

Comment: One second seems way too long. You can use the java compiler as an API within the JVM and you can immediately load the resulting class to the running JVM.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I'm seeing 0.7s real time and 1.2s user time (because of multithreading, presumably). Can you go significantly below that with the compiler API?

Comment: What are you testing? `javac` at the command line? When used inside the JVM I think you can have a stable "hot" setup where everything's loaded except the one source file you are compiling. Compilation time should be in the milliseconds.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yes, I edited the question

Comment: I have no idea how it works under the hood, but Java 9 will include a REPL. This link offers a preview: https://www.jclarity.com/2015/04/15/java-9-repl-getting-started-guide/

Answer (score 1):

So, if your source language is *Java*, there really isn't.  There are a few tools that let you load and interpret Java from a REPL, but Java's semantics really depend on being able to resolve things like class relations.

There are, however, JVM languages that can be used without pre-compiling, eg, Clojure, Scala, and Groovy.

Comment: Clojure is hideously slow to start up.

Comment: Yes, the source has to be Java. What are those REPL tools? Do they bypass the 1s compilation?

Comment: Ah. REPL is "read-eval-print loop".  In a language like Clojure, LISP, or Groovy, there is a program that *reads* input, *evaluates it* as a program, then *prints* the result and *loops* back to read again.  But the structure of the java language means it needs to be compiled somehow, even if you don't see it.  

You might hava a look at this: https://repl.it/languages/java

Comment: Groovy still generates bytecode, even when run as a "scripting" language

Comment: As does pretty much every interpreted language written more recently than the homebrew BASIC I wrote in 1974.